# Share the product information for two different views

Tags: store-view, language

I want to use for 2 different store views the same language.

Is possible make it without copy the same information in the two storeviews?

I want to share the information of a store view for two.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/overview-how-multiple-websites-stores-work/

Comment: hi, if you define product information in default store view (admin) all your store views inherit from it.

Answer (score 1):

Product information is by default shared between all store views if the product is not specifically created with details for only 1 store.

So when creating a product make sure at the top left under 'Choose Store View' that this is set to 'Default Values' and the information you enter for that product will show for all store views.

You can also set completely different product information for a specific store view by selecting it from the 'Choose Store View' drop down, changing the values as needed and saving the product.